# How to prevent chrome from always looking for a proxy?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

Every time my computer restarts, Chrome wants to use a proxy server. So when I open up the browser, it says the webpage is unavailable, and I have to go to `Settings > Advanced Settings > Change proxy settings > LAN settings` and deselect the "Use a proxy server for your LAN" box.

I do not require a proxy for my connection, and I have never manually set one up. How can I prevent this option from being selected on every reboot?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the the `Automatically detect settings` checkbox is also deselected.

[image: LAN Setting Screenshot]

Comment: Did not work. :(